# Restricting url manipulation to return other user records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just begun Rails 3. I have generated the below code using the scaffold from Rails 3 on a table called "Logs".

The 'index' function below provides only the records associated with the current_user.id (from the session stored in the session table). The users records are only presented with the following route logged in as user = 3 (see index code below)

> localhost:3000/logs

**Problem:** As a user, I can view a record which is not my record (being user=3) by editing the url manually to show any other record:

> localhost:3000/logs/5            'this was entered by user.id=2'

**Seeking Solution**: How do I prevent manually hacking of the url to prevent a user viewing other user records?

> class LogsController < ApplicationController
>
> before_filter :login_required
>
> ```
> def index 
>   @logs = Log.where(:user_id => current_user)
>   respond_to do |format|
>   format.html # index.html.erb
>   format.xml  { render :xml => @logs }
> end
> ```

Please ignore that the new function is missing from the create function below. The code below is to merely demonstrate how I put the user_id into the "Logs" table

> ```
> def create
>  @log = Log.new(params[:log])
>  @log.user_id = current_user.id
>   respond_to do |format|
>   if @log.save
>     format.html { redirect_to(@log)}
>     format.xml  { render :xml => @log, :status => :created, :location => @log }
>   else
>     format.html { render :action => "new" }
>     format.xml  { render :xml => @log.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
>   end
> end
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to check in the show method if the Log to display really belongs to the logged in user:

```
def show
  @log = Log.find(params[:id])
  unless @log.user_id == current_user.id
    flash[:error] = "unauthorized"
    redirect_to :index
  end
end
```

But you will soon have some more things you want to restrict access to, so you should look for an authentication plugin which allows to define the access rights in a declarative manner. Maybe this one: https://github.com/be9/acl9

Comment: Many thanks for the ACL recommendation. Authentication is obviously different to authorisation. Still in my infancy with Rails and everything I seem to read blurs between Ruby syntax and Rails syntax. I have tested your code and it works by preventing url manipulation. When manipulating the url, it presents only the users records. However, I noticed that the flash error will never eventuate.

Comment: Sorry, I now see the "Unauthorised" when mamipulating the URL. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: You're right, I meant authorization, sorry for mixing that up. The flash message is not shown? You need a statement in your view which outputs messages if present. I don't know if the generator creates this automatically.